# Iterate a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, iteration, tuples

I'm looking for a clean way to iterate over a list of tuples where each is a pair like so `[(a, b), (c,d) ...]`. On top of that I would like to alter the tuples in the list.

Standard practice is to avoid changing a list while also iterating through it, so what should I do? Here's what I kind of want:

```
for i in range(len(tuple_list)):
  a, b = tuple_list[i]
  # update b's data
  # update tuple_list[i] to be (a, newB)
```

Comment: Well, you're not really updating the list with that one, you're only updating the tuple.

Comment: Right, so something like `tuple_list[i] = (a, newB)`... except I want to avoid doing this inside the loop. I'm curious if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: @Clever: The loop you've given is fine; it doesn't iterate through the list you're updating but just the indexes. This is a completely standard way to work with lists, as long as you're not changing the number of elements in the list, which you're not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just replace the tuples in the list; you *can* alter a list while looping over it, as long as you avoid adding or removing elements:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(tuple_list):
    new_b = some_process(b)
    tuple_list[i] = (a, new_b)
```

or, if you can summarize the changes to `b` into a function as I did above, use a list comprehension:

```
tuple_list = [(a, some_process(b)) for (a, b) in tuple_list]
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you go for a list comprehension instead of altering it?

```
new_list = [(a,new_b) for a,b in tuple_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

here are some ideas:

```
def f1(element):
    return element

def f2(a_tuple):
    return tuple(a_tuple[0],a_tuple[1])

newlist= []
for i in existing_list_of_tuples :
    newlist.append( tuple( f1(i[0]) , f(i1[1]))

newlist = [ f2(i) for i in existing_list_of_tuples ]
```

Comment: Why use `tuple(...)` when just `(...)` would do?

Comment: just to be more readable.  there were a hole lot of parenthesis going on there.

Comment: I don't find that to be more readable; it instead distracts, it makes me think you are casting another sequence type to a tuple instead.

Comment: i'll agree with you on the `f2` function.  but in the append function... `newlist.append(tuple(f1(i[0]),f(i1[1]))` vs `newlist.append((f1(i[0]),f(i1[1]))`.  i find the former much more readable.