# How can i get a list of key-value pairs from a list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I have the following code except that gives me the following list of tuples

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    checkbox_values = request.form.getlist('service_name')
    print(type(checkbox_values)) //for debugging
    print(checkbox_values) //for debugging

[u"(u'ZOL Zimbabwe', u'Fibre Internet')", u"(u'ZOL Zimbabwe', u'Wimax Internet')", u"(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Fibre Internet')", u"(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Wimax Internet')"]
```

In simple english , the first value in every tuple is the ISP name and the second value is the service provided by that ISP

What i need to achieve is being able to have a reference of the first value and the second value.

If i do this

```
values =     [u"(u'ZOL Zimbabwe', u'Fibre Internet')", u"(u'ZOL Zimbabwe', u'Wimax Internet')", u"(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Fibre Internet')", u"(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Wimax Internet')"]

for x in value:
    print k
```

i get this

```
(u'ZOL Zimbabwe', u'Fibre Internet')
(u'ZOL Zimbabwe', u'Email Hosting')
(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Fibre Internet')
(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Wimax Internet')
(u'Utande Internet Services', u'Email Hosting')
```

i need a way of referencing these values so i can grab them and insert into a database

i looked into these links ,but every method is giving me an error

[Tuple unpacking in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops)

[Iterate a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880192/iterate-a-list-of-tuples)

[iterating quickly through list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021571/iterating-quickly-through-list-of-tuples)

and I am still reading those links ,in case i am missing something ,someone can point me to the right direction

Comment: You don't have tuples. You have *strings with parentheses in them*. They are probably produced *from* tuples, but someone passed them to the `unicode()` function.

Comment: Printing those strings will write out text that *looks* like Python syntax, but they are still strings.

Comment: Put differently: fix the code that produced those strings, and leave those tuples as tuples. You can undo the damage with `ast.literal_eval()` but you'd be much better off not creating these results in the first place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the code that is producing that is this                           `if request.method == 'POST':
        checkbox_values = request.form.getlist('service_name')`

Comment: So why does the server send you Python literals as strings, and not as, say, JSON?